# Will a many-to-many table with billions of records cause performance issue?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many, nosql

I'm building a database contains 3 tables.

1. Users table, (ID, UserName)
2. Products table, (ID, ProductName)
3. Rating table, (ID, UserID, ProductID, Rating)

I potential will have nearly 100m users and 5000 products. Although not every user rated every product, it's still reasonable to assume that my Rating table will have billions of records. My knowledge of database is limited to SQL queries, so I'm wondering will it become super slow when I wish to select all ratings made by one particular user.

Thanks

Update: Regarding to the Rating table, is it necessary or has any benefits to keep ID column, if I make `UserID` and `ProductID` as Primary Key? When it comes to modelling, I'm only using one user's ratings at a time, i.e. select all ratings belong to user1, do stuff on these records, select user2 ratings, do stuff on these records, so on and so forth. In terms of convenience and efficiency, any better database structure than many-to-many table?

update2:

```
| time_spent | CREATE TABLE `time_spent` (
  `product_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `minutes_spent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `index_product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

where product_id is 6 digits long, but might become longer in the future; user_id is 17 digits long.

Comment: Not at all.  You just need an index on `ratings(UserId)` or better yet `ratings(UserId, ProductId, Rating)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `ID` on the many:many table; you have a 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY(UserID, ProductID)`.  Use InnoDB so that the `Rating` will be clustered with the PK, hence 'covering'.  So you don't need the 3-column index Gordon suggested.

Will you need to go the other way?  If so, `INDEX(ProductID, UserID, Rating)` is indicated so you can get a 'covering' index that way, too.

[7 tips on many:many tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

**Addenda**

If you `SELECT` the (up to) 5000 rows for one User, and you have `PRIMARY KEY(UserId, ProductID)` and InnoDB, all those rows will be in a few dozen blocks.  So, even with a cold cache we are talking about less than a second.  If you need to `UPDATE` all 5000 rows, then you are touching the secondary key (if it exists) and that is on the order of 5000 disk hits -- a lot of overhead, though InnoDB's 'Change buffer' deals with it in a delayed manner.

So, if you don't need to go from Prod to User (such as finding all the ratings for a Product), leave off the secondary index.

Comment: Since these are real time data, I need to frequently select all up to 5000 rows of each user, then compare these rows with up to date data, finally update these rows have changed. Is it enough just setting `(product_id, user_id)` as primary key? Thanks

Comment: `(user_id, ...)` is efficient for finding lots of rows for one user; `(product_id, ...)` is efficient for finding lots of rows for one product.

Comment: I set `(user_id, product_id)` as `PRIMARY KEY` and `product_id` as an additional index. The only problem is the 3-column table eats disk space very crazy

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I want to see the datatypes, etc.

Comment: A small improvement would be to use something smaller than a 4-byte `INT` for `minutes_spent`.  It seems like the table (and its index) will take about 100 bytes per row; is that what you are seeing for "eats disk space"?

Comment: If you don't need to go 'from product_id', then dropping the index would save about half the space.

Answer (score 0):

Database schema describe above is good to go. Just make sure add composite index on (UserID and ProductID) and that should do. Regarding performance, there is a possibility of small hit because of billions of records as you mentioned and considering database is of significant size. But you can't do much about it, just beef up database machine.

I would not consider removing id from ratings table. I know its not serving any direct purpose. But what I have seen is ID table is very useful(make things little simpler) when you end up writing complicated queries and joins.

Comment: The queries involving a many-to-many table are very limited; I doubt if they every can make use if `ID`.  Also `ID` is clutter and overhead.  For billions of rows, any clutter is costly.